# Hashing password and login

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I trying to hash the password while I create new user. This is what I have when user is added:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$options = [
'cost' => 11,
'salt' => hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) . 'dsdsajJDSK&&^*^%FKLD876' . strtolower($username)),
];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password)
           VALUES (:username, :password)";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
         ':username' => $username,
        ':password' => $hash                                
        ));
```

And in database is stored something like this

> $2y$11$fbd730bf81fe115d43283uAjC849wT.rD1F7CuBHEJHCVIVNn
>   The in my login file I have this

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'misc/database.inc.php';
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) 
{
     $pdo = Database::connect();
     $username=$_POST['username']; 
     $password=$_POST['password']; 

     $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");

     $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
     $stmt->execute();
     $res  = $stmt -> fetch();
     if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $res["password"]))
     {

         if ($res['level'] == 1)
         {
             $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
             header( "location: admin/main.php");   
         }
         elseif ( $res['level'] >= 4 ) 
         {
             $_SESSION['user_id']   = $res['user_id'];
             $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
             header('Location: users/main.php');
         }
         else 
         {
             header("location: index.php");              
         }
         $pdo = null;
     }
} else {
?>
 // html
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that I have user which has old `sha1` password and I'm able to log with this user. I think it must not be able to log?

UPDATE:

```
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);

$stmt->execute();
$res  = $stmt -> fetch();
if(password_verify($password, $res["password"])){
//if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $res["password"])){
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't you also need to add the salt to the login routine you show in the second block? It clearly shows in the creation routine that you salt with a garbage string plus the username, you're doing no such thing in the second routine.

Comment: The username weakens the salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) needs is the user's password and the hash from the database. You don't need to hash anything yourself again.

Instead, you should just use:

```
if(password_verify($password, $res["password"])){
// or
if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $res["password"])){
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. I've got blank pages in both ways.

Comment: Updated with full login script

Comment: I just don't understand then why this doesn't work on my login form and I got blank page

Comment: @Goro Any errors? Check the error log and / or enable error display in the page itself.

Comment: I've tried with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` but still blank page.

Comment: @Goro It's unclear what your script looks like now, you've replaced the "add user" script with a login script (it seems...) that is missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: Oh, my mistake yes .. I've wanted to replace second block for login but I'm replaced the adduser. I'll fix it but I don't have missing `}` after last `else` I have html where is the form and then is `<?php } ?>`

Comment: I fixed the question with `adduser` and `login` form. Now should be a bit clear..

Answer (score 1):

The password_verify() function also works with other hash algorithms. The first part $2y (in this case BCrypt) tells the function which algorithm was used to generate the hash, so it can use the same algorithm for verification.

```
$2y$11$fbd730bf81fe11...
```

Some tips to improve your code:

Do not create your own salt, especially not one which is a derrived from other parameters. Just let the function create a safe salt:

```
$options = array("cost" => 11);
```

Put an exit() after each header(...) otherwise the script continues anyway.

```
if ($res['level'] == 1)
{
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  header( "location: admin/main.php");
  exit();
}
```